# Blank response from jQuery Ajax call to PHP script

Tags: php, ajax, forms, jquery

I hope this isn't a duplicate; the other similar questions I read didn't help me solve my problem.

I'm receiving a blank response (i.e. data = "") from a jQuery Ajax call to my PHP script, used to validate a user's submitted CAPTCHA value. I'm using [Cryptographp](http://www.captcha.fr/) for my CAPTCHA, and it works as expected, so I'm thinking it's most likely an error either in my Ajax call or the PHP script.

**Firebug showing correct POST values ('code' is the submitted CAPTCHA value to test):**

```
code      a
email     a@a.com
emailtext a
firstname a
lastname  a
phone
```

**Ajax function called onsubmit to determine whether or not to submit the form:**

```
function validateCaptcha()
{
  // Assume an invalid CAPTCHA
  var valid = false;

  // The form containing the CAPTCHA value
  var data_string = $('form#emailform').serialize();

  // Make the Ajax call
  $.ajax({
    url: "captcha.php",
    data: data_string,
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
      if (data == "true")
      {
        valid = true;
      }

      alert ("data: " + data);
    }
  });

  return valid;
}
```

**captcha.php**

```
<?
  $cryptinstall="crypt/cryptographp.fct.php";
  include $cryptinstall;

  // Begin the session
  session_start();

  //Check if CAPTCHA values match
  if(chk_crypt($_POST["code"]))
    return true;
  else
    return false;
?>
```

My expectation is that the above snippet should return a response of simply "true" or "false," but perhaps this is not the case.

Any help pointing out my error would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As an aside, I've noticed many people criticize making synchronous calls with Ajax (duh, *A*jax, I know!). Any explanations why I would want my form submission to be asynchronous/non-blocking would be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use "echo" instead of "return" and write is as a string. return is for returning results of functions.

```
    <?
      $cryptinstall="crypt/cryptographp.fct.php";
      include $cryptinstall;

      // Begin the session
      session_start();

      //Check if CAPTCHA values match
      if(chk_crypt($_POST["code"]))
        echo "true";
      else
        echo "false;
    ?>
```

Comment: D'oh! Dumb mistake on my part. I've just been working with functions for too long recently. Works as expected now. :)

Answer (score 2):

From your `captcha.php` you are not echoing/printing anything so it's returning nothing. Just replace your `return true;` and `return false;` with echo.

Browser can only receive something when you'll print something from the script.

```
if(chk_crypt($_POST["code"])) echo true; // 1
else echo false;// 0
```

or

```
if(chk_crypt($_POST["code"])) echo 'true'; // true
else echo 'false';// false
```

Comment: Yes, I just now realized my mistake. Thanks for the response. :)